# Data contracts: Ignore unknown types on deserialization

Tags: c#, deserialization, datacontract

I have a plugin-based host application. Its settings are described as a data contract:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class HostSetup
{
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<Object> PluginSetups
    {
        get
        {
            return pluginSetups ?? (pluginSetups = new ObservableCollection<Object>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Object> pluginSetups;          
}
```

Any plugin has its own settings type. E. g.:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Plugin1Setup
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Plugin2Setup
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Percent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

At run-time, the user has configured host and plugins such a way:

```
        var obj = new HostSetup();
        obj.PluginSetups.Add(new Plugin1Setup { Name = "Foo" });
        obj.PluginSetups.Add(new Plugin2Setup { Percent = 3, Amount = 120.50M });
```

Then, my application has saved its settings via DataContractSerializer. Plugin types were passed as known types to the serializer's constructor.

**The question.**
User physically removes assembly with "Plugin2" and then starts up my application.
So, when the host receives a list of available plugins, it knows nothing about serialized "Plugin2Setup" instance.

I want to ignore this instance, and let the user to work without "Plugin2" settings.
Is there any elegant way to do this?
I can store plugins' settings as data contracts serialized into strings:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> PluginSetups
```

but it's not handy and ugly.

**Edit 1**
The problem is how to deserialize HostSetup instance and ignore serialized Plugin2Setup instance.

**Edit 2**
My current solution is:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class PluginSetupContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    private String typeName;
    [DataMember]
    private String rawData;

    [OnSerializing]
    private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (SetupParameters != null)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer))
            {
                var setupParametersType = SetupParameters.GetType();
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(setupParametersType);
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, SetupParameters);

                xmlWriter.Flush();

                typeName = setupParametersType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
                rawData = writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    [OnSerialized]
    private void OnSerialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        ClearInternalData();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawData))
        {
            var setupParametersType = Type.GetType(typeName, false);
            if (setupParametersType != null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StringReader(rawData))
                using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader))
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(setupParametersType);
                    SetupParameters = serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
                }
            }

            ClearInternalData();
        }
    }

    private void ClearInternalData()
    {
        typeName = null;
        rawData = null;
    }

    public Object SetupParameters { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class HostSetup
{
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<PluginSetupContainer> PluginSetups
    {
        get
        {
            return pluginSetups ?? (pluginSetups = new ObservableCollection<PluginSetupContainer>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<PluginSetupContainer> pluginSetups;
}
```

May be it's terrible, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think ideally you should have something on the lines of

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[MyPluginCustomAttribute]
public class Plugin1Setup
{
}
```

and when you application loads you should initialize `obj.PluginSetups` using reflection based on `MyPluginCustomAttribute` so only assemblies that are present have their types registered. So you won't have the problem of missing assemblies. You can also use **[Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com/)** instead of your own `MyPluginCustomAttribute`

Comment: The question is not "how to receive a list of available plugins and their settings types" or "how to initialize plugin settings".  The problem is the deserialization of object graph containing unknown types.